# Google Bigquery SELECT timeouts with simple joins

Tags: join, google-bigquery

This simple query is timeouting, any ideas how to optimise it using some BigQuery tricks?

```sql
SELECT
s.typeFlight s_type, r.distance, r.price, (d.booking_token IS NULL) clicked
FROM [search.searches] s
LEFT JOIN [search.search_results] r ON r.searchid=s.searchid
LEFT JOIN [search.clicks] d ON d.booking_token=r.booking_token
WHERE s.saved_at BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2016-03-01 00:00:00')
AND TIMESTAMP('2016-03-05 00:00:00')
```

Query settings

- Query Priority   **Batch**
- Destination Table    **bucket-984:search.result**
- Write Preference **Overwrite table**
- Allow Large Results  **true**

The data comes from search engine, so the table *clicks* is small (under million rows) but the table *searches* and *search_results* are huge. The query processes about 5 TB of data.

Answer (score 0):

You could push the where filtering into the first select so there's less data to join:

```
SELECT
s.typeFlight s.type, r.distance, r.price, (d.booking_token IS NULL) clicked
FROM (
  SELECT typeFlight, type, searchid
  FROM [search.searches]
  WHERE saved_at BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2016-03-01 00:00:00')
    AND TIMESTAMP('2016-03-05 00:00:00')
) s
LEFT JOIN [search.search_results] r ON r.searchid=s.searchid
LEFT JOIN [search.clicks] d ON d.booking_token=r.booking_token
```

Sometimes it is helpful to look at the Query Plan Explanation https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation to see where your query is spending time.

Comment: It is still timeouting.